# Jquery Search collapse

Tags: jquery, search

I have a search bar that is hidden. When I click a link it fades in. It's a different DIV.

I would like to close it when I click the link itself (to make it appear) but also when clicking outside of the element that appears.

My current code works when I click outside of the element. The search bar disappears. But when I click the link itself it re-appears.

How do I fix that?

```js
$(".search-toggle").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $("#search-toggle-nav").slideToggle('slow', function() {
    $(".search-toggle").toggleClass('active');
  });
  $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    var container = $("#search-toggle-nav");
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
      container.fadeOut();
    }
  });
});
```

I have a WordPress menu with the link Search. I wan to achieve

- When click on search the searchbar appears.
- When click outside of the searchbar I want to close it.
- When click the Search link again (in the menu) I want to close it.

```html
<div class="section--top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row between-xs">
      <div class="mobile-navigation"></div>

      <nav id="top-navigation" class="top-header-navigation navigation">
        <?php
                        wp_nav_menu( array(
                'theme_location' => 'menu-4',
                'menu_id'        => 'top-menu',
                        ) );
                    ?>
      </nav>
      <!-- #site-navigation -->
      <nav id="social-navigation" class="top-social-navigation navigation">
        <?php
                wp_nav_menu( array(
                            'theme_location' => 'menu-5',
                            'menu_id'        => 'social-menu',
                        ) );
                    ?>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="search-toggle-nav" class="panel">
  <div class="search-wrapper">
    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you assigning a handler inside another handler? That is never a good idea

Comment: Please explain. I'm new to jQuery.

It is not working when I place it outside of the first handler.

Comment: can you provide html as well. So that we can have better idea what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Done, I've added the HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following code, it's not tested, but should do its job.

As you can see [HERE](https://codex.wordpress.org/it:Riferimento_funzioni/get_search_form) the search form has default `id` values, so you can set an handler to the input field, whenever it loses focus, you can `fadeOut` its container.

```
$(".search-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#search-toggle-nav").slideToggle('slow', function() {
        $(".search-toggle").toggleClass('active');
    });

});

$('#s').on('focusout', function(e) {
    $("#search-toggle-nav").fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $(".search-toggle").removeClass('active');
    });
});
```